# Fallo Ejercicio Basico PHP

Tags: php

Hola buenas me gustaría saber que fallo tiene...Se que es un ejercicio básico de PHP, no me acaba de ejecutar bien la linea del for...
Debería crear una fila de tabla con sus tr y dos th internos en uno un numero (euros) , y en otro esa cifra multiplicada por pesetas...

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML LANG="ES">

<HEAD>
   <TITLE>PHP y HTML</TITLE>
   <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="estilo.css">
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    
<H1>PHP y HTML</H1>

<table width="200" border="">
         <tr>
             <th>EUROS</th>
             <th>Pesetas</th>
         </tr>     
             
<?PHP
      
  $n = 166.338;
    
   for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){ 
    print ("<tr><th>$i</th><th>$n*$i</th></tr>");
          
   }
?>   
         </table>
<br>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Añade el error que te genera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes solucionarlo concatenando los valores asi:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML LANG="ES">

<HEAD>
   <TITLE>PHP y HTML</TITLE>
   <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="estilo.css">
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<H1>PHP y HTML</H1>

<table width="200" border="">
         <tr>
             <th>EUROS</th>
             <th>Pesetas</th>
         </tr>     

<?PHP

  $n = 166.338;

   for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){ 
    print ("<tr><th>$i</th><th>".$n*$i."</th></tr>");

   }
?>   
         </table>
<br>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Me ejecuta mal...

Comment: Que es lo que sale mal?

Comment: He añadido el resultado que me ejecuta..

Comment: Agregalo a tu pregunta, no a mi respuesta.

Comment: A mi me funciona bien con este codigo, pareciera que tienes una comilla de mas.  Intenta copiar y pegar  el codigo.